# GWT, Open/view just window class on tests

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT, I want to know if there is a way to test and object that extends a Window class in GWT.
Is it possible to open just this window in chrome in same way.  I would love to test this on junit.  Just to deploy me window so I could test it before deploying the whole project.

```
public class WinAhorroPrg extends Window
```

It would save me so much time.

just call in it test like

```
@Test
public void testWindowWinAhorroProg{
/*some other classes/code*/
winAhorroPrg.show();
}
```

And then open it on 
http://localhost:8888/testWindow

By the way I am using a really old version of gwt (2.1.1) that I am not allowed to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GWT the `Window` class provides access to the **browser** window's methods, properties, and events. Running in Junit you won't have the browser. There's an emulation of a browser, called [HtmlUnit](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingHtmlUnit.html), that maybe will help you to think in a way to implement your tests. Have a look at the [GWT Testing Guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html) as well.

Comment: Is HtmlUnit included after GWT 2.0 with GWT or you need to add the jar?

Comment: @JuanDiego Actually, `HtmlUnit` is not part of GWT. But GWt has support for that. My suggestion is to check if you GWT version has the enumeration `Platform.HtmlUnit` or the class `RunStyleHtmlUnit`. It'll indicate that it's compatible.